# How to implement Azure Message Queue in the WebAPI

Tags: azure, message-queue, webapi

I have multiple WebApi that are hosted in Azure but some of the API taking a long time to process.
Instead of a calling from the scheduler function in Azure, I was advised to use the Messaging Queue.

Is this a good approach?
Also, let say my API URL.. **https://testwebapi.net/api1** and **https://testwebapi.net/api2**, how can we communicate these API using Message queue and also how to call the WebAPI individually from Messaging Queue?

Is this Azure Bus service is the same as Messaging Queue for Azure.

Answer (score 0):

I would strongly recommend you look at the respective docs on Azure, and start doing some quick tutorials and post more specific questions.

Now, to answer, what I believe is your main question, Azure Bus Service and Messaging Queue.

The thing is, there is no one Messaging Queue, rather three options for Azure messaging -  Service Bus, Event Grid, and Event Hubs. Also, there is something called 'Azure Queue Storage', but I dont think you are thinking of that, considering your context.

There is a very cool comparison chart available here - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/compare-messaging-services

But, I think, my guess, is you are looking for ultimately looking to use Azure Service Bus.

Also, please understand that one does not invalidate the other. As your project develops, you may end up using Azure Service Bus with other options like Event Hubs or Grids or all of them in different places.

Also, you keep using the incorrect terms. for example, you say 'Azure Bus service' but its really 'Azure Service Bus'. Also, there is no thing called 'Messaging Queue for Azure.' as there are so many different messaging services for Azure. This is what I want to add here. Spent some time with the docs and post more specific questions as you continue your project.

Comment: Just wanted to confirm which is best in my case?
Like as I have already mentioned I have 16 WebAPI and that is a long-running process,it takes time to run.
Currently, I am running a timer function in azure that run all the APIs but there is an issue My APIs get a timeout
because of the long-running process.
I was asked to use the Messaging service in Azure as an alternate of timer function that can run these APIs without a timeout.
Can you please confirm which one is best in my case? and also how can I call these API from Messaging Service in Azure without timeout or any fail?

Comment: I would say, a mix of Event Hubs with Service Hub is your best option at this point. If I were, I would start by building a simple system of say 3 APIs (not production code but something which you can share in a public repo), setup up the event hubs and service hubs and see if you can get the desired results. Once this setup is ready, you will run into issues, and then, you can start posting specific questions. Right now, your question is very generic and unless we have more info, its hard to help.